# why cke editor always add cke to my embed, object, param ..?

Tags: ckeditor

this is my script :

```
CKEDITOR.replace(
    'editor1', {
       "filebrowserImageUploadUrl": "<?php echo config_item('instMasterUrl').'imgupload' ;?>"
    }
);
```

with :

```
config.extraAllowedContent  = 'div[id]; object[id,name,width,height];'+
'param[name,value];embed[src,type,allowscriptaccess,allowfullscreen,wmode,width,height]';
```

when post one video from youtube like this:

```
<object width="560" height="315">
    <param name="movie" value="//www.youtube.com/v/znK652H6yQM?hl=id_ID&amp;version=3&amp;rel=0"></param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="//www.youtube.com/v/znK652H6yQM?hl=id_ID&amp;version=3&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="560" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
</object>
```

ckeditor always add cke: in the beginning becomes:

```
<cke:object width="560" height="315">
    <cke:param name="movie" value="//www.youtube.com/v/znK652H6yQM?hl=id_ID&amp;version=3&amp;rel=0"></cke:param>
    <cke:param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></cke:param>
    <cke:param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></cke:param>
    <cke:embed src="//www.youtube.com/v/znK652H6yQM?hl=id_ID&amp;version=3&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="560" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></cke:embed>
</cke:object>
```

and by now, i can not open the flash ..
how to prevent cke add that prefix to my code?

Comment: How do you get data from CKEditor?

Comment: i get data from php, let's say <textarea class='editor1'>my flash object tag here</texarea>

Comment: Ok, so I cant' reproduce your problem. I initialised CKEditor in the way you did this, pasted the HTML which you attached here and when I switch back to source mode I can see the correct `<object>` tag and the rest. Please create a sample on which this will be reproducible.

Comment: here is my video on how i made it ..: www.youtube.com/watch?v=JoIafhNNlFU

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to insert flash you should rather install the [flash plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/flash).

Second of all, I asked how do you get the data to exclude possibility that you access CKEditor's internals, because that's not data. You get the data by `editor.getData()` or when you submit the form. What's inside editor is a totally different story.

Third of all, even with the flash plugin enabled, you won't see the flash inside editor, but just a placeholder. If you expect a different behaviour, you would need to look for a different plugin - maybe one for inserting Youtube videos, or some oEmbed one. Check out the [addons repository](http://ckeditor.com/addons/plugins/all).

Comment: how can we see the video if only placeholder inside the editor? this is my first ckeditor experience, i still confuse about the data. what for that function? i need the flash shown as in my video above, what should i do? would you guide me step by step?

Comment: I have similar problem: when I insert object into CKEditor (in my case PDF) it shows embed PDF, but when I destroy editor and then make new instance, `<object>` tag changes to `<cke:object>` so it's not visible (its content is shown instead). So when I start CKEditor, I either edit content of that tag accidentaly, or (when I use `protectedSource`) I can't see where my object is (so I don't know if I'm typing before or after it). I would like to have visible PDF while editing - as it is when I put object tag into running CKEditor. Can you help me how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor by default protects object/param/embed tags. To prevent it from changing your embed tag you have to CKEDITOR.FILTER_SKIP_TREE for that element when CKEditor is loading these tags. If you are using a plugin to insert embedded media it is best to write editor.filter.addElementCallback as per http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.filter